# Custom variations select script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, woocommerce

So, i have a custom script to change the default WooCommerce variations select, so far so good, the problem is when a variation is out of stock, the custom select should have the same options as the default select.

Custom "select" above, default below. Branco and P are out of stock.

[image: Custom "select" above, default below. Branco and P are out of stock.]

I found out that the [WooCommerce Variations JS](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js) remove out of stock options programmatically, but as my script runs after Variations JS i thought it should work. I manage to make it work adding a setTimeout of 2000ms, but that is too much and it actually breaks other functions i have. I will be grateful if someone knows how to solve this.

```js
$('.variations select').each(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var div = $('<div class="grupo-atributos">');
    var ul = $('<ul>');
    select.parent('.value').siblings('.label').find('label').each(function(){
      var label = $(this).text();
      div.append('<span>'+label+'</span>');
    });

    $('#custom-select-produto-variavel').append(div);
    div.append(ul);

    select.find('option').each(function(){
      var titulo = $(this).text();
      var data_value = $(this).val();
      ul.append('<li data-value='+data_value+'>'+titulo+'</li>');
    
    select.change(function(){
    select.find('option:selected').each(function(){
      var opcao_selected = $(this);
      select.find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(){
        var opcao_not_selected = $(this);
        $('#custom-select-produto-variavel li').each(function(){
          var opcao_custom = $(this);
          if(opcao_custom.attr('data-value')==opcao_selected.val())
              opcao_custom.addClass('atributo-selected');
          if(opcao_custom.attr('data-value')==opcao_not_selected.val())
              opcao_custom.removeClass('atributo-selected');
        });
      });
    });
    }).change();

    });
  });

  $('#custom-select-produto-variavel div ul li:contains("Escolha uma opção")').remove();

  $('#custom-select-produto-variavel ul li').click(function() {
    var novoVal = $(this).data('value');
    $('.variations select:has([value='+novoVal+'])').val(novoVal);
    $('.variations select').trigger('change');
  });
```

```html
<div id="custom-select-produto-variavel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the variation select has a delay of 100ms to start, so to make my script work correctly i needed to add those lines.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
 // My script
}, 150);
});
```